# Selecting random words from an generating a sentence from an input file

Tags: c++, fstream

I need to create a program that has 4 columns of words from an input file.

[image]

then randomly selects a word from each column and generates a sentence. The ultimate goal is to have a conversation that gets saved to the output file.

[image]

I've already created the code that reads the input file, and opens the output file to write on but i'm not sure how to select a word from a column and create the sentence, i'm guessing using an array would work but i'm not certain how to connect it with the file?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string ifilename, ofilename, line;
    ifstream inFile, checkOutFile;
    ofstream outFile;
    char response;

    // Input file
    cout << "Please enter the name of the file you wish to open : ";
    cin >> ifilename;
    inFile.open(ifilename.c_str());
    if (inFile.fail())
    {
        cout << "The file " << ifilename << " was not successfully opened." << endl;
        cout << "Please check the path and name of the file. " << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The file is successfully opened." << endl;
    }

    // Output file

    cout << "Please enter the name of the file you wish to write : ";
    cin >> ofilename;

    checkOutFile.open(ofilename.c_str());

    if (!checkOutFile.fail())
    {
        cout << "A file " << ofilename << " exists.\nDo you want to continue and overwrite it? (y/n) : ";
        cin >> response;
        if (tolower(response) == 'n')
        {
            cout << "The existing file will not be overwritten. " << endl;
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    outFile.open(ofilename.c_str());
    if (outFile.fail())
    {
        cout << "The file " << ofilename << " was not successfully opened." << endl;
        cout << "Please check the path and name of the file. " << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The file is successfully opened." << endl;
    }

    // Copy file contents from inFile to outFile

    cout << "Hi, what's up? " << endl; // Pre-set opener

    while (getline(inFile, line))
    {

        cout << line << endl;
        outFile << line << endl;
    }

    // Close files
    inFile.close();
    outFile.close();
} // main
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 2D vector of strings to store the words of the sentences and use a random number generator like [rand](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/) to pick a particular row element from every column. Something like the following

```
vector<vector<string>> myConversationVector;
while (choice != "no")
{
    std::cout << myConversationVector[rand() % 5][0]  <<" "
              << myConversationVector[rand() % 5][1]  <<" "
              << myConversationVector[rand() % 5][2]  <<" "
              << myConversationVector[rand() % 5][3];

}
```